# Process JSON Array

Tags: webservices, json, rest, deserialize

Can someone tell me how to process JSON Array in an Apex REST resource class ?.

My input to the HTTP post method will be like as follows.

```
[  
   {  
      "Name":"1 A"
   },
   {  
      "Name":"1 B"
   }
]
```

I did some study on this and found out that I need to utilize JSON Deserialize as follows.

```
public class CompanyDeserialize {
    public String Name;
    List < CompanyDeserialize > complist = (List < CompanyDeserialize > ) JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, CompanyDeserialize.class);
    System.debug('~~~~ complist :' + complist);
    List < Account > alist = new List < Account > ();

    for (Account a: complist) {
        alist.add(new Account(Name = a.Name));
    }
    System.debug('~~~~ alist :' + alist);
    insert alist;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to incorporate the above JSON deserializing code snippet into the webservice class below as I am not sure how to pass the JSON array as parameter to this `createAccounts()` method ?

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping = '/Account/*')
 global class AccountWS {
    @HttpPost
    global static void createAccounts() {
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Deserialize the Json Array to a list of accounts like this `List<Account> accountsDeserialized = (List<Account>) JSON.deserializeStrict(jSONRequestBody, List<Account>.class);` Please find the below example tried with a JSON Array. I used Workbench for testing.

**Apex class**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/accounts/*') 
global with sharing class AccountWS {
    @HttpPost 
    global static void doPost(){
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        String jSONRequestBody=request.requestBody.toString().trim();
        List<Account> accountsDeserialized = (List<Account>) JSON.deserializeStrict(jSONRequestBody, List<Account>.class);
        insert accountsDeserialized;
    }
}
```

**JSON Array**

```
[  
   {  
      "Name":"1A",
      "Phone":"5555555555"
   },
   {  
      "Name":"1B",
      "Phone":"4444444444"
   }
]
```

**Workbench**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/accounts/*') 
global with sharing class AccountWS {
    @HttpPost 
    global static void doPost(){

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        Map<String, object> retValues = new Map<String, object>();
        Map<String, object> values = 
        RestfulServiceUtils.parseJsonFromRequest(req);
        List<Object> lst = (List<Object>)values.get('accpuntsDetails');
        for(object o : lst)  {
         Map<String,object> mapData = (Map<String,Object>)o;
         system.debug(mapData.get('Name'));
         system.debug(mapData.get('Phone'));   
        }
        res.responseBody = RestfulServiceUtils.parseValToJson(retValues);

    }
}
```

**Your JSON**

```
{
    "accpuntsDetails": [{
            "Name": "1A",
            "Phone": "5555555555"
            },
        {
            "Name": "1B",
            "Phone": "4444444444"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer? If so can you please **[edit]** your post to include at least a little bit of explanation?